How to set camera z-axis orientation in Meshcat via Drake?
I would like to update the pose of the default camera of the Meshcat viewer in Drake to effectively be attached to a moving body frame throughout a simulation. I can get the pose of body in the world frame from the scene graph, and I can set the camera's position and view direction using meshcat.SetCameraPose(...). However, with the current API I am unable to force its orientation to match that of the frame I want it to be "connected" to. It's "roll" about the camera z-axis stays fairly constant as it translates around and changes its pointing direction.
Is there a way to set the full camera transform, rather than just its position and pointing direction (either in Drake, Meshcat, or through some call to the underlying three.js camera object)?
The meshcat API indicates that you can force the camera to be at a specific transform by calling:
meshcat.SetTransform('/Cameras/default', RigidTransform(...))
meshcat.SetProperty('/Cameras/default/rotated/<object>', 'position', (0, 0, 0))

However, when I do this, the camera moves to the desired position, but it continues to point at (0, 0, 0).

Good question; I'd have to dig into this. As the meshcat API indicates, there is a specific camera controller instantiated that dominates orientation. To drive the camera's 6-dof value, that controller would have to be disabled. That implies a change to  meshcat itself.
